# Racemic compound widely available

Tags: symmetry

Can racemic compounds be found at the local drug store non-prescription? Where might one be found most readily/cheaply? Only one chiral center is needed. More may actually be unhelpful. The purpose here is to practice separating enantiomers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know that ibuprofen is sold as racemic mixture, it's a drug for fever treatment. It's very cheap in Brazil, one dollar each box (400mg per tablet).

[image]

Comment: I think ibuprofen is common and cheap everywhere, possibly with a few exceptions.